# Glossaries with 3 columns gives error with missing item

Tags: glossaries

I try to create a glossary with 3 columns, but continuously I get the following error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [...etentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}]
```

Here is my minimal "working" example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{iulstyle}{%
% put the glossary in a longtable environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{longtable}{lp{2cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
 {\end{longtable}}%
% Set the table’s header: title row
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
 \bfseries Zeichen & \bfseries Einheit & 
 \bfseries Beschreibung
 \\\endhead}%
% No table header:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% No heading between groups:
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[3]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{##2}% Name
    & \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units
    & ##3% Description
    \\% end of row
 }}%

 %% Entry
\newglossaryentry{sym:A}{%
name={$F$},%
description={bar},%
user1={cm}%
}

 \begin{document}
 test: \gls{sym:A}


\setglossarystyle{iulstyle}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.6\textwidth}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

The compilation is done with `makeglossaries`.

Help is very appreciated,
Christian

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you wanted to define your glossary style as

```
\newglossarystyle{iulstyle}{%
% put the glossary in a longtable environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{longtable}{lp{2cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
 {\end{longtable}}%
% Set the table’s header: title row
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
 \bfseries Zeichen & \bfseries Einheit &
 \bfseries Beschreibung
 \\\endhead}%
% No heading between groups:
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryuseri{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
}
```

to get

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{iulstyle}{%
% put the glossary in a longtable environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{longtable}{lp{2cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
 {\end{longtable}}%
% Set the table’s header: title row
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
 \bfseries Zeichen & \bfseries Einheit &
 \bfseries Beschreibung
 \\\endhead}%
% No heading between groups:
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryuseri{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
}

 %% Entry
\newglossaryentry{sym:A}{%
name={$F$},%
description={bar},%
user1={cm}%
}

 \begin{document}
 test: \gls{sym:A}


\setglossarystyle{iulstyle}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.6\textwidth}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did the trick right now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Christian you're welcome.